# Percentage of Variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sum, average, percentage

I have two tables. The condition is from one table example find **"Spanish"** movies from one table and then find the % of its views which is a column in another table.

What I am doing:

```
Select movie,
SUM(CASE WHEN movies = 'Spanish', then views/sum(views))
from table A 
left join table B on ID
group by movie
```

Is being calculated as `views/views`, it is not calculated as `view A / TOTAL SUM OF VIEWS`.

Any ideas how I keep the condition in table A and then find the % of Total from another table?

---

Example tables:

- Table 1: Clients: { IDKlient, Salary }
- Table 2: Exposures: { IDKlient, Exposure }

I need to get all clients that have salary above 10k and their exposure as percentage of total exposue

Comment: your syntax is wrong and it doesn't make sense. Can you post the table you're working with and the desired result?

Comment: I know is wrong. I am looking for the right one. I cannot share the table unfortunately, so that is why I tried to explain what syntax I am trying to get.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: " I cannot share the table unfortunately"? What do you mean? Don't you know how to copy and paste table data or do you think the table data must be kept top secret? If the latter, then just make up some data. A few rows of each table, so we see what you are talking about. (It usally doesn't help either to use generic table names like A and B. Thus it is even harder to understand the database.) Why is movie a column and not a table? Is this supposed to be the movie title? And you want one row per movie, no matter whether the movie is Spanish or why else don't you have a where clause?

Comment: Please mention the dbms you are using.

Comment: Please provide sample data. Don't give exact data. Just show the sample structure & data of both tables & the result you expect from the query

Comment: Table 1 has IDKlient, Salary. Table 2 has IDKlient  and Exposure.

I need to get all ID Clients that have a salary above 10 000 and calculate their exposure as % of total exposure. 

I will try the solution from @KaziMohammadAliNur tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of your question, you have 2 tables like,

#### movies

```
+----+-------+----------+
| id | movie | lang     |
+----+-------+----------+
| 1  | ABC   | English  |
-------------------------
| 2  | XYZ   | Spanish  |
-------------------------
| 3  | LOL   | Chinese  |
-------------------------
| 4  | FYI   | Spanish  |
-------------------------
| 5  | BBC   | Spanish  |
+----+-------+----------+
```

#### views

```
+----+-------+
| id | views |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 810   |
--------------
| 2  | 570   |
--------------
| 3  | 190   |
--------------
| 4  | 250   |
--------------
| 5  | 745   |
+----+-------+
```

Then your expected result should have ***"movie name"*** & its ***"view percentage"*** queried by *language*

#### query

```
SELECT
  m.movie,
  (100 * sum(v.views) / (select sum(views) from views)) percentage
FROM movies m
JOIN views v on v.id = m.id
WHERE lower(m.lang) = 'spanish'
GROUP BY m.movie
ORDER BY m.id;
```

###### output

```
+-------+------------+
| movie | percentage |
+-------+------------+
| XYZ   | 22.22      |
----------------------
| FYI   | 9.75       |
----------------------
| BBC   | 29.04      |
+-------+------------+
```

##### Reference: [SQL Fiddle running example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fea34b/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum()over()` window function instead of `sum()`

`views/sum(views)over()`

You need something like that (please mention your DBMS name):

```
select movie, movie_percentage from
(Select movie,
sum(views)over(partition by movie)/sum(views)over() movie_percentage
from table A 
left join table B on A.ID=B.ID
)t where movie='Spanish'
```